# Liquibase random 'Permission denied' error

Tags: java, spring, mariadb, liquibase

In our project, we are using Java (Spring) with Liquibase to manage the DB (MariaDB) stuff.
We have 400+ changesets and a recurring issue annoys us again and again.
The issue: in case we drop our local DB and run the Liquibase update (or the Spring app), the first 100-200 changesets run successfully, but then we have an error with the following message:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Migration failed for changeset db/changelogs/datastructure/*changelog-name*:
 Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: (conn=64) Error on rename of '******' to '*****' (errno: 13 "Permission denied") [Failed SQL: (1025) ALTER TABLE ***** ADD ***** VARCHAR(50) NULL, ADD ***** VARCHAR(50) NULL]
```

After such event we usually need to start over from dropping the DB due to conflicts (most of the changesets which fail cannot be roll backed properly by Liquibase).
The interesting part is that we are getting this error each time to different changeset.

Additional infos:

- We are using a user with all the privileges.
- Tried with a non-root user with all the privileges, still fails.
- Our app is deployed to 3 different environments and we haven't experienced this error on those environments.
- We have a couple of integration test, and using pretty much the same changesets to build up the test DB, no issues there either (the test DB is on the same instance but with a different DB name).